# Rails 3.2.12 and mongoid 3.0.17, observers can't be initialized,

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I was trying to create a observer to do something when a product is created of update.

The product model is under the namespace "ecommerce", and the path is "app/models/ecommerce/product.rb"

```
class Ecommerce::Product
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :market_price, type: Float, default: 0.0
  field :price, type: Float
  field :stock, type: Integer, default: 999
  blah...blah...blah

  belongs_to :shop, :class_name => "Ecommerce::Shop"
end
```

And then I made a observers folder under app, and made a observer class for the above model. The path is "app/observers/ecommerce/product_observer.rb"

```
class Ecommerce::ProductObserver < Mongoid::Observer
  observe :ecommerce_product

  def after_create(ecommerce_product)
    # do something
  end
end
```

In the application.rb, I have used a loop to load the observers to config.mongoid.observers like the code below (it's been tested, working fine here)

```
config.mongoid.observers = Dir["#{config.root}/app/observers/**/*.rb"].collect do |full_name|
  File.basename(full_name,'.rb').to_sym
end
```

Finally I tried to restart the rails server, and the error below came up on the terminal

```
/Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@opn/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:
in `block in constantize': uninitialized constant ProductObserver (NameError)
```

I was just wondering is there anything I missed for observing the namespaced model?
Could anyone help? Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `File.basename` is stripping off the ecommerce directory.  So it's just left with `'product_observer'` which becomes `ProductObserver` without the namespace.

Comment: Any idea with my case if I want to keep namespace? thanks in advanced.